# second click for interacting with inputs in window, when iframe: true

Tags: iframe, kendo-ui

when kendo window `iframe` option set to `true`

controls inside window get focus only after second click

http://jsfiddle.net/b64g1kjv

we have a widget dashboard, where all windows are pinned and do not overlap at any time,

therefore `click-click` behaviour is meaningless in our case

are there any workarounds?